# how do i whitelist the elastic beanstalk servers that are in private subnet in ec2 server that is in public subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have an elasticbeanstalk environment whose ec2 instances are in Private Subnet.
I have another stand-alone ec2 server in Public subnet. I want to whitelist the elastic beanstalk server in standalone ec2 server. However since elastic beanstalk servers does not have fixed IP's, iam not able to selectively whitelist them in security groups.

Answer (score 1):

Security groups (SGs) can **reference other security groups**. So this is how you normally do what you want to do. Namely, create a rule in your EB's SG, to allow connections from SG of other instance.

This will only work for private traffic, not over internet. But from what you wrote, it seems that this is what you are concerned with. Otherwise, if this is about internet traffic, then you can't do this without static IP address.